# Rails 7.0 with turbo back button is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I am building an app with rails 7.0

```
<turbo-frame id="<%= item.id %>">
  <div><%= item.id %></div>
  <div><%= item.item_type %></div>
  <a href="<%= edit_item_path(item.id) %>"  
               data-turbo-frame="_self">
     edit item
  </a>
</turbo-frame>
```

The edit view loads the new content successfully, but there is no back button functionality on this scenario. How can I enable back button?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `data-turbo-action="advance"` in my link, although according to the documentation that behaviour should be the default one.

```
 <a href="<%= edit_item_path(item.id) %>"  
              data-turbo-frame="_self"
              data-turbo-action="advance">
```